# Returning a string based on the value between two integers

Tags: javascript

Fairly simple one for ye but can anyone advise me on where i'm going wrong please? I just need to return either "Easy", "Moderate" or "Hard" based on the integer input into the textbox.

**HTML**

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action=""> 
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Score:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="enter" id="enter" size="1"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="result" id="result" disabled /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
function update() { 
  var v = document.getElementsById('enter')[0].value;
  var output = v;
  if ((v > 1) && (v <= 10)) = "Easy";
    else if ((v > 11) && (v <= 20)) = "Moderate";
    else ((v > 21) && (v <= 30)) = "Hard";
   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = output;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add details on what's wrong with your code ?

Comment: you may want to use getElementsByTagName('enter')[0] or getElementById('enter')

Comment: This example should work just fine http://jsfiddle.net/rfLe9krx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Score:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="enter" id="enter" size="1" onchange="update();"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="result" id="result" disabled /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    'use strict';

    function update() { 
        var v = document.form1.enter.value;
        var output = '';
        if (v > 1 && v <= 10) {
            output = "Easy";
        } else if (v > 10 && v <= 20) {
            output = "Moderate";
        } else if (v > 20 && v <= 30) {
            output= "Hard";
        }
        document.getElementById('result').value = output;
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be made a lot more readable!

What do you do if `v` is `>30`?  What about `1` or `11` or `21`? I've used `"Impossible!"` as a placeholder for you in this example:

```
function update () { 
    var value = document.getElementsById('enter')[0].value;
    var difficulty = "Easy";

    if (value > 30) {
        difficulty = "Impossible!";
    }
    else if (value > 20) {
        difficulty = "Hard";
    }
    else if (value > 10) {
        difficulty = "Moderate";
    }
    else {
        difficulty = "Easy";
    }

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = difficulty;
}
```

or, you could use a `switch` statement with conditionals, like so:

```
function update () {
    var value = document.getElementsById('enter')[0].value;
    var difficulty;

    switch (true) {
    case (value > 20 && value <= 30):
       difficulty = "Hard";
    break;
    case (value > 10 && value <= 20):
        difficulty = "Moderate";
    break;
    case (value > 1 && value <= 10):
        difficulty = "Easy";
    default:
        difficulty = "Impossible!";
    break;
    }

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = difficulty;
}
```

Comment: `case (> 20 && <= 30):` the case statement gets evaluated, but this syntax is wrong. instead of this you can use `switch(true)` and `case (value > 20 && value <= 30):`.

Comment: @rookie very true.. I kinda threw that up in a hurry just to show it could be done different ways. will update

Answer (score 0):

```
function update() { 
  var v = document.getElementById('enter').value;
  var output;

  if ((v > 1) && (v <= 10)) output = "Easy";
  else if ((v > 11) && (v <= 20)) output = "Moderate";
  else if ((v > 21) && (v <= 30)) output = "Hard";

  document.getElementById('result').value = output;
}
```

Where do you think you are assigning this literal string values to? And you cant put a condition with a else statement.

Comment: You can't set the input element value using `innerHTML` either, also a problem with `document.getElementsById('enter')[0]` *(Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function)* You should debug your answer before submitting.

Answer (score 0):

I did post a link to a jsfiddle but here's the demo

```js
window.onload=function(){
  document.getElementById('enter').addEventListener('input', update,false);
}

function update() { 
var v = document.getElementById('enter').value;
var result;
 if ((v > 0) && (v <= 10)) result = "Easy";
    else if ((v > 11) && (v <= 20)) result = "Moderate";
    else result = "Hard";
   document.getElementById('result').value = result;
}
```

```html
<td>Score:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="enter" id="enter" size="1"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="result" id="result" disabled/></td>
```

I recommend you strip anything but 0-9 for that input and I have removed `document.getElementsById('enter')[0].value` should be `document.getElementById('enter').value`.

Also `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result;` has been changed to `document.getElementById('result').value = result;` as you want to set the value of the input element, not innerHTML.

> **Edit:** `(v > 0)` if level 1 is selected it will output "hard" as it return true to the else and not the conditions set.

If you have any questions please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!